# Set default value in 'react-native-dropdown-picker'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using `react-native-dropdown-picker` in my project. I have an array of states which is like this: `[{value: "Bagerhat"},{value: "Bagerhat"}]`. So, in ComponentDidMount i'm changing this array by `[{label: "Bagerhat"},{label: "Bagerhat"}]` because react-native-dropdown-picker needs label in it's item's array. Here's my `DropDownPicker` component :

```js
componentDidMount() {
       var sts = [{value: "Bagerhat"},{value: "Bagerhat"}]
   sts = sts.map(item => {
        return {
         label: item.value
         };
    });
   this.setState({
     states: sts
        })
    }

        <DropDownPicker
              items={this.state.states}
              defaultValue={(this.state.state !== ''? this.state.state : null )}
              containerStyle={{ height: 50,width: width - 40,alignSelf:'center' }}
              style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
              itemStyle={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}
              dropDownStyle={{ marginTop: 2, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
              onChangeItem={item => this.setState({state:item.label})}
            />
```

Now `this.state.state` is present like 'Bagerhat' for example. But it's showing error for `label` is undefined. Why it's throwing this error. On dropdown it's showing states if i remove defaultvalue but defaultValue is throwing label error for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: What is `this.state.state` in your case?

Comment: It's just string like "Bagerhat" @LeriGogsadze

Comment: It should be key-value pair I think. `{ label: "Bagerhat" }`

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is crashing is it can't take null as a default value, You should remove ternary if else in default value and set this.state.state in constructor as an example below,

```
export default class Picker extends Component {
   constructor(){
     this.state={
        state:'',
     }
  }
}
```

And in return function , change that to

```
<DropDownPicker
      items={this.state.states}
      defaultValue={(this.state.state)}
      containerStyle={{ height: 50,width: width - 40,alignSelf:'center' }}
      style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
      itemStyle={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}
      dropDownStyle={{ marginTop: 2, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
      onChangeItem={item => this.setState({state:item.label})}
    />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. It gives the same error.